# Timer works with println but not label using java

Tags: java, swing, timer

I have some labels that become visible when the letter a is pressed.

```
private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A){
        jLabel7.setVisible(true);            
        jLabel8.setVisible(true);
        jLabel9.setVisible(true);
        myBlink();
    }
```

I have Label8 on a timer myBlink()

```
public void myBlink()
    {
    new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                    
            System.out.println("begin");
            jLabel8.setVisible(false);
            jLabel8.setVisible(true);
            System.out.println("Timer");
        }
    }).start();
    }
```

I have placed printlns to see if timer begins and ends and when I press key "a" my output shows begin Timer multiple times but my label does not appear and disappear.  What tweak does this code need?  What am I missing?  Thanks for the extra set of eyes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because you call successively `setVisible(false)` and `setVisible(true)` which is done too fast to be seen, you should use a variable and modify its value any time the action of the `Timer` is called as next:

```
public void myBlink()
{
    new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        boolean visible = true;
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jLabel8.setVisible(visible = !visible);
        }
    }).start();
}
```